# How can i know app idle time?

Tags: android, idle-timer

I have an android app it displays web view.I want know the app idle time because If session expires i want go to my android login activity how can i do it. Please provide any suggestions for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start chronometer inside pause method and once activity resumed you can get the duration through chronometer. for code reference :

```
// create a instance for chronometer
Chronometer duration = new Chronometer(this);

// starts chronometer inside pause override method
duration.setBase(0);
duration.start();

// you also need to add onTick listener.
duration.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
            NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
            long countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0.getBase()) / 1000;
            String asText = formatter.format(countUp / 60) + ":" + formatter.format(countUp % 60);
        if (is_pause == false) {
            duration_time = asText;
        } 

// once done stop the chronometer inside stop override method and set a flag, check      this falg inside OnTickListener and get the duration asText.
duration.stop();
is_pause = false;
```